# Wordpress REST API not displaying all information

Tags: rest-api, json

[Here](http://immo.mymakler24.ch/) is the WP site.

And [here](http://immo.mymakler24.ch/wp-json/) is the site's REST API.

Now if you go to the real estate listings page on the site [here](http://immo.mymakler24.ch/immobilie-kaufen/), you will find 2 dummy listings, but when I try to search for data of those listings in the API, it is not showing, but since the data is public, shouldn't it be available via the default Wordpress API for my site as well?

Answer (score 1):

The link doesn't give any information.

- site shows blank page
- the rest api returns authentication error.

WP Search API is working pretty well for post post-type as a default.
When you publish the posts, it takes a couple seconds to admit them in the rest search results. In my past experience, Searching didn't work due to the caching issue.

Comment: Can you tell me how to make the REST API publicly accessible as in require no authentication? Because once that happens, My question will make sense.

Comment: @Grey-lover Check your wordpress version, since 4.7 it's WP Rest API enabled by default. If it's over the version, check your plugins. It can turn off WP REST Api. I think your coming soon plugin might make the issue. Turn it off, Then check it again.

Comment: Hi you were right, The coming soon plugin was making it inaccessible. The pages are now accessible, could you help me out with the original query now? :)

Comment: I read somewhere its happening because I have to manually register new taxonomis/custom post types to the rest api in order for rest api to display them? Do you think that's it?

Comment: @Grey-lover When CPT is registered, the default value of 'show_in_rest' is false. So you should turn it true, and it will be included in rest results.